# soundblaster creative x ae 5: dualboot / card in bad state after booting debian

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, alsa

i have a soundblaster creative x ae 5 soundcard and i really like to play with that in windows. but most of the time i use my workstation with debian or fedora. when i boot fedora and then windows, i have no problems. but as soon as i boot debian and then windows, the card is broken. when i play any audio file, it sounds like from a horror movie. so debian does something that brings the card in a state, where its absolutely broken. i have to unplug the workstation from the power to get it back working. anyone an idea what could cause that? i dont think its alsa, because then i would have the same problem in fedora.